# How can I pipe a passcode into ssh perhaps using the utility yes?

Tags: ssh, expect

How can I pipe a passcode into ssh? I have in mind something like the following, using the utility `yes`:

```
yes mySuperSecretPasscode | ssh user@topsecretserver.foo
```

This still results in ssh requesting manual entry of the passcode.

Note that I am aware of ssh keys and so on. I have reasons for trying to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

`yes` will repeat whatever you give it as fast as possible until it is stopped.
You should rather try `echo` for piping. That said, you probably want to use key based authentication, as storing your password in plain text is not a good idea.

Look at https://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password for a guide to key based authentication. Just leave the key passphrase empty to avoid being prompted when logging in.